# Wait for Animation Inside of Form Submit Event

Tags: jquery, forms, post

## Submitting Form After jQuery Execution

The way I have my form currently set up the user can select one of several options, each represented by a button with a unique value. What I'd like to do is process the form data and then execute an animation if everything checks out. My problem is that if I use `.preventDefault()` I can't get the form to submit with the chosen button value properly, without `preventDefault()` the animation doesn't occur always (I can get it to work sporadically but that isn't really an acceptable solution).

Just to be clear, the desired behavior is to detect a form submission with an event listener, execute an animation upon submission, and redirect the page while sending the value of the button that was selected via POST to the next page.

I tried

- using `$("input").click()`
- using `$("form").submit()`

**Here is the HTML I was Using to Experiment**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body{
      padding:100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    form{
      margin:20px auto;
      padding:20px;
      border:solid black 2px;
      width: 400px;
      background-color:red;
    }
    form input[type='submit']{
      display:block;
      width:200px;
      height:40px;
      margin:10px auto;
    }
    form input[type="submit"]:hover{
      background-color:grey;
      font-weight:bold;
    }

    .hidden{
      display:none;
    }
    #sqare{
      margin:20px auto;
      background-color:black;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['my_button'])){
    echo $_POST['my_button'];
  } 
?>

<form id="ver_form" method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" value = "Button No. 0" name = "my_button">
  <input type="submit" value = "Button No. 1" name = "my_button">
  <input type="submit" value = "Button No. 2" name = "my_button">
  <input type="submit" value = "Button No. 3" name = "my_button">
</form>

<div id="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a warning: If you're doing this on a form with `target="_blank"`, this may well trigger the pop-up blocker of the user's browser, because it tries to open a window from code that *isn't* running in *immediate* response to a user event.

But assuming you're staying in the same window: A combination should do it:

1. Remove the `name` of your submit buttons entirely.
2. Add a `type=hidden` field with `name=my_button`
3. On a `click` of a submit button, set the form's `my_button` hidden field to the button's value.
4. Use your example `submit` handler **but** change how you submit the form after the end of the animation to:

   ```
   form[0].submit();
   //  ^^^---- note
   ```

   `form.submit()` calls jQuery's `submit` method, which will re-trigger the `submit` event. `form[0].submit()` calls the DOM `form` element's `submit` function, which does *not* re-trigger the `submit` event.

So combining the `click` and `submit` handlers:

```
$(function(){
  var form = $("form");
  // On a click on a submit button, set the hidden field's value
  form.find("input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    form.find("[name=my_button]").val(this.value);
  });
  // On form submit...
  form.submit(function(e){
    // Prevent the submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // Start the animation
    $("#square").toggle(100,function(){
      // It's done, do the submission NOT with jQuery's `submit` function
      form[0].submit();
    });
  });
});
```

With this updated HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value = "Button No. 0">
<input type="submit" value = "Button No. 1">
<input type="submit" value = "Button No. 2">
<input type="submit" value = "Button No. 3">
<input type="hidden" name = "my_button">
```

Complete example, doing a GET to google.com using `q` instead of `my_button` so we see the result in their search page based on which button you press:

[Live Copy on JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/horupo/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="submit" value = "Kittens">
<input type="submit" value = "Puppies">
<input type="submit" value = "Unicorns">
<input type="submit" value = "Bunnies">
<input type="hidden" name = "q">
</form>
<div id="square">I'm the square</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  var form = $("form");
  // On a click on a submit button, set the hidden field's value
  form.find("input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    form.find("[name=q]").val(this.value);
  });
  // On form submit...
  form.submit(function(e){
    // Prevent the submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // Start the animation
    $("#square").toggle(100,function(){
      // It's done, do the submission NOT with jQuery's `submit` function
      form[0].submit();
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```